# yes/No . Is $f(n) =( [n]_I , [n]_J )$ injective

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Is the following statement True/false ?

> let $I , J \subseteq R$  are ideal  such that $I +J= R $, then the  function $ f : R \to R/I  \times R/J $ defined by $f(n) =( [n]_I , [n]_J )$ is    injective

**My  attempt** : I think this  statement is false

take  $I=2\mathbb{Z}, J=3\mathbb{Z}$ ,and $R= \mathbb{Z}$

Now ,$ f : \mathbb{Z}\to \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}  \times \mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z} $ defined by

$f(x) =([x]_3, [x]_5)$ is not injective  because  $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}  \times \mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z} \cong \mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}$

Also , $ f : \mathbb{Z}\to \mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}$ defined by $f(x)=[x]_{6}$ is not injective

Am i right ? also i am not able to find out  the ideal that  satisfy the  above statement

Comment: your "$I=2\mathbb{Z}, J=3\mathbb{Z}$ does not provide a counterexample. See Chinese remainder theorem

Comment: okay @AnneBauval actually  that  is $ f(x)= ([x]_2,[x]_3)$

Comment: yes@AnneBauval by chinese remainder theorem $f$ will subjective but not injective

Comment: Study directly the condition on $I,J$ for $\ker f$ to be 0

Comment: @AnneBauval   why  kerf to be $0$ ? because  $2 \mathbb{Z} \cap 3\mathbb{Z}= 6\mathbb{Z} \neq 0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct, the statement is false. And your counterexample works fine for this, but not for the reason you gave.
The ideals $\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb Z}2\Z$ and $3\Z$ of $\Z$ indeed satisfy that $2\Z+3\Z=\Z$, but the function
$$
f \colon \Z \to \Z/2\Z \times \Z/3\Z, \quad f(x) = ([x]_2,[x]_3)
$$
is not injective since its kernel is $2\Z \cap 3\Z = 6\Z$.

The correct statement should be

> If $I$ and $J$ are ideals of $R$ such that $I+J=R$, then the function
> $$
> f \colon R/(I \cap J) \to R/I \times R/J, \quad
> f([x]_{I \cap J}) = ([x]_I,[x]_J)
> $$
> is injective.

Comment: And by the way, if $I + J = \langle 1 \rangle$ then it follows that $I\cap J = IJ$, so you can also write an injective function $R / (IJ) \to (R/I) \times (R/J)$.

Comment: okay @azif00  can you give an example of $2$nd  statement that satisfy $f([x]_{I \cap J}) = ([x]_I,[x]_J)
$is injective

Comment: @jasmine The second statement is always true.

Comment: okay@azif00 let me check

Comment: @azif00 that mean for  $2$nd statement we have $2\mathbb{Z} \cap 3\mathbb{Z}= 6\mathbb{Z} \mod (6)=0$, $Kerf =\{0\} \implies  f$ is injective .Am i right ?